# Como faço para popular o UsuarioLogado, e usar seus dados para popular a View?

Tags: java, android

MVP é uma coisa nova para mim e venho tendo algumas dificuldades. Gostaria de saber, como eu deveria criar uma classe pra receber os dados do meu usuario logado do banco de dados Firebase para popular a minha View.
Pensei em usar um Singleton, vi em alguns exemplos que ele é uma opção, mas que não é ideal por dificultar a testagem do código, então como eu deviria criar essa classe que preciso de acesso quase que o tempo todo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha dica para você é utilizar injeção de dependencias, isso irá deixar o codigo testavel e ao mesmo tempo, poderá ter acesso relativamente facil aos objetos que você quer frequentemente.

As bibliotecas famosas para injeção de dependencias para android são:

- [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?hl=pt-br), bem nova, e beem facil de começar, baseada e utiliza componentes do dagger, então pode ficar tão robusta quanto o dagger se precisar.
- [Dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger), uma robusta e mais complexa para começar.
- [Koin](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin), mais fácil que o Dagger e tão boa quanto, facil de começar e com sintaxe mais "kotlin".